# Composer could not find the config file - using Jenkins on Windows

Tags: php, jenkins, ant, composer-php

I have an Ant build script that is trying to execute `Composer install` but I get this error when executed through Jenkins:

```
     [exec] Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
     [exec] To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
     [exec] Result: 1
     [echo] composer update complete
```

Here is the target from Ant:

```
<target name="self-update"
        if="composer.self-update"
        unless="composer.installed"
        description="Self-update Composer">
    <echo message="Self-updating composer" level="debug"/>
    <exec executable="${composer.phar}">
        <arg value="self-update" />
        <arg value="--quiet" />
        <arg value="--no-interaction" />
    </exec>
    <echo message="composer self-update complete" level="debug"/>
</target>
```

However, this works fine when running the Ant build locally.

Some people say to delete the environment variables that the composer installer sets; however it does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an environment variable named `COMPOSER` that was set to `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`. The variable was not visible through the `Environment Variables` control panel.

I could work around this by setting the `env key="composer"` to `""`.

```
<target name="composer"
        depends="init, self-install, self-update"
        if="composer.run">
    <condition property="composer.command" value="update" else="install">
        <available file="${composer.lock}"/>
    </condition>
    <echo message="Beginning composer ${composer.command}" level="debug"/>
    <exec executable="php">
        <env key="composer" value=""/>
        <arg value="${composer.phar}"/>
        <arg value="${composer.command}"/>
        <arg value="--verbose"/>
        <arg value="--no-interaction"/>
        <arg value="--optimize-autoloader"/>
        <arg value="--prefer-dist"/>
    </exec>
    <echo message="composer ${composer.command} complete" level="debug"/>
</target>
```

It's also possible set it to `composer.json`.